# getting noclassdeffounderror cordova

Tags: java, android, cordova

I have an issue while creating a cordova plugin. I use an api in the form of jar. I called a method in **MeshLibraryManager.class** which internally calls its constructor. This constructor calls a method of **App.class**.
I'm experiencing **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.csr.csrmeshdemo2.App** error. But both classes(MeshLibraryManager.class and App.class) are located in same jar.

Here is the method in **MeshLibraryManager.class**

```
public static void initInstance(Context context, MeshChannel channel,LogLevel logLevel) {

    if (mSingleInstance == null) {

        mSingleInstance = new MeshLibraryManager(context, channel,logLevel);
        mSingleInstance.start();
    }
}
```

Here is the constructor of MeshLibraryManager.class

```
private MeshLibraryManager(Context context, MeshChannel channel,LogLevel lgLevel) {
    // Log message has a tag and a priority associated with it.
    logLevel= lgLevel;
    App.bus.register(this); // THIS IS WHERE I GET NoClassDefFoundError
    mContext = new WeakReference<Context>(context);
    mCurrentChannel = channel;
    Intent bindIntent = new Intent(mContext.get(), MeshService.class);
    context.bindService(bindIntent, mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

Here is the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hc4MU.png) I get and screenshot of [jar structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AiEm.png)

how can get rid of this error?

Comment: can you post your gradle?

Comment: Here is the gradle file [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5Y7xXR5wysJUkZEWVZmRTE3dzQ/view?usp=sharing)